# How to select max(date) in Big query without using a window function?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to select the latest date in a string field called stamp: '20160523'. I can transform it by DATE(stamp), but when I try to query MAX(DATE(stamp)) it doesn't select the latest date, but just outputs the transformed timestamp '2016-05-23'.

{SELECT MAX(DATE(stamp)) FROM  WHERE a=b... }

Any ideas what am I doing wrong and how to do it without using a window function?

Many many thanks ina dvance!
G

Comment: Where is the group by here MAX needs a group by.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, but it's not clear what is exactly your problem because it's works perfectly for me

```
SELECT MAX(a) FROM (SELECT DATE('20160523') as a), (SELECT DATE('20170301') as a)
```

You can copy-paste it and run, it's very useful for understanding how operators work. 
But I don't recommend use MAX for string (as DATE returns string). Use MAX with timestamps like

```
select date(max(a)) from (select TIMESTAMP('20160523') as a), (select TIMESTAMP('20170301') as a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the query below.

```
select max(x) from UNNEST([ TIMESTAMP('2017-07-01T14:59:55.711Z'), TIMESTAMP('2021-07-01T14:59:55.711Z')]) as x
```